# File Cache option is missing

Tags: joomla-3.x, performance, cache

I am running a Joomla 3.3.6 site in a hosted environment (Startlogic) and I see that my File Cache Handler option is no longer available.  It used to be an option at some point and now it is gone.  Cache_Lite is currently my only option.  I have found that for my site the File Cache Handler was much faster so it would be nice to have it back.

I have a cache directory and it is set to 755 permissions.

This article was helpful but not really my situation : [Joomla cache handler only shows memcached](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/joomla-cache-handler-only-shows-memcached)